# Are these checking on the pass-in parameters necessary?

Tags: c#

I have listed five different scenarios that I think the null-checking is necessary in the product code. Although, most of the reference books I have checked do NOT make such checkings. It is reasonable to ignore those checking while the original reference tries to deliver the other important ideas. Here, I summarize all my concerns as follows and please correct me if there are errors.

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Student() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}", Name);
    }
}

class StudentNameComparer : IComparer<Student>
{
    public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
    {
        if ( (x == null) || (y == null) ) // <C1> Should we check there?
            throw new ArugmentNullException("bla bla");

        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
    new Student("s1"),
    new Student("s4"),
    new Student("s3"),
    new Student("s2")
};
students.Sort(delegate(Student x, Student y) 
    { 
        if ( (x == null) || (y == null) ) // <C2> Should we check there?
            throw new ArugmentNullException("bla bla");

        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);    
    });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
    new Student("s1"),
    new Student("s4"),
    new Student("s3"),
    new Student("s2")
};
students.Sort( (x, y) => 
    {
        if ( (x == null) || (y == null) ) // <C3-1> Should we check there?
            throw new ArugmentNullException("bla bla");

        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);    
    });
Or
students.Sort( (Student x, Student y) => 
    {
        if ( (x == null) || (y == null) ) // <C3-2> Should we check there?
            throw new ArugmentNullException("bla bla");

        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);    
    });
////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
    new Student("s1"),
    new Student("s4"),
    new Student("s3"),
    new Student("s2")
};
foreach (Student std in students.OrderBy(p => 
    { 
        if (p == null) // <C4> Should we check there?
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("...");
        }
        return p.Name;                
    }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(std);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, just take a look at the interface [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare.aspx).

In fact, what is done there in the `IComparer` is wrong.

> The preferred implementation is to use the CompareTo method of one of the parameters.
>
> Comparing null with any type is allowed and does not generate an exception when using IComparable. When sorting, null is considered to be less than any other object.

So `Compare()` must not throw just because one of the elements is `null`.

Since we established that, the `Sort` method doesn't need the check, as we can see above that `null`s sort just fine.

No idea on the last example, though. I believe throwing is a bit harsh in that case. However, `null`s should probably not appear in your collections, anyway. If I have a list of students at least it doesn't make much sense to me to include `null`s there.

Something like

```
p => p != null ? p.Name : string.Empty
```

could be used instead (which would be consistent with the ordering that is imposed by default on `null` values).

Comment: I am confused here. Similar code is mentioned in on page10 of C# In Depth 2nd.

Comment: Confused about what specifically? Compare must not throw on `null` and most of the other checks are moot, then.